# Java android java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed:

Tags: java, android

When I did this :

```
  private class CustomInfoWindow extends MarkerInfoWindow {
        POI mSelectedPoi;

        CustomInfoWindow(MapView mapView) {
            super(R.layout.bonuspack_bubble, mapView);
            Button btn = (Button) (mView.findViewById(R.id.bubble_moreinfo));
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(final View view) {
                    Singleton si = Singleton.getInstance();
                    ObjectDefExtends obj = si.getCurrentObject();
                    if (obj != null && Singleton.getInstance().getListaVisible().size() > 0) {
                        ObjectDefExtends currentObject = si.getCurrentObject();
                        double latitude = currentObject.lat;
                        double longitude = currentObject.lon;
                        String label = currentObject.name;
                        String uriBegin = "geo:" + latitude + "," + longitude;
                        String query = latitude + "," + longitude + "(" + label + ")";
                        String encodedQuery = Uri.encode(query);
                        String uriString = uriBegin + "?q=" + encodedQuery + "&z=16";
                        final Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);

                        Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
                                switch (msg.what) {
                                    case 1:
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                                        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                                        finish();

                                    default:
                                        break;
                                }
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                        handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(1, 1000);

                        onResume();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onOpen(Object item) {
            super.onOpen(item);
            mView.findViewById(R.id.bubble_moreinfo).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Marker marker = (Marker) item;
            mSelectedPoi = (POI) marker.getRelatedObject();
        }
    }
```

I see a black window and in logs I see this :

```
03-17 12:29:53.852 7671-7671/maps E/ActivityThread: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.smok.maps/maps.logowanie.LoginActivity}
                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.smok.maps/com.smok.maps.logowanie.LoginActivity}
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3462)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3549)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:174)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1334)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You should not call the android lifecycle callbacks manually

Comment: @MehmetKologlu when I remove call onResume it is going this same

Comment: O I never claimed that it would solve your problem, just pointing out a very bad practice